# An elegant way to make transformation of something like transpose in pandas faster

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a `pandas.Dataframe` called `a` and the structure is as follows:
[image: the structure of <code>a</code>]

while I want to get the `DataFrame` structure is like:

[image: the structure of <code>b</code>]

where the `b` is like the transpose of `a`.
By convert `a` to `b`, I use the code :

```
id_uni = a['id'].unique()
b = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id']+[str(i) for i in range(1,4)])
b['id'] = id_uni

for i in id_uni:
    for j in range(7):
        ind = (a['id'] == i) & (a['w'] == j)
        med = a.loc[ind, 't'].values 
        if med:  
            b.loc[b['id'] == i, str(j)] = med[0]
        else:
            b.loc[b['id'] == i, str(j)] = 0
```

The method is very brutal that I just use two for-loops to get all elements from `a` to `b`. And it is very slow. Do you have an efficient way to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
print (df.pivot(index='id', columns='w', values='t'))
w    1    2   3
id             
0   54  147  12
1    1    0   1
```

---

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='id', columns='w', values='t').reset_index()
df1.columns.name=None
print (df1)
   id   1    2   3
0   0  54  147  12
1   1   1    0   1
```

Comment: wow!! It works. And then I use `.reset_index(inplace=True)`, but the name `w` is still in the index, how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Thanks !! But can you share with me why you can find the method so quickly? I don't how to find the exactly api I want...

Comment: Hard question - maybe some experience, I like data reshaping. You can also check [SO docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pandas/1463/reshaping-and-pivoting/4770/simple-pivoting#t=201612081457390951027).